# How to remove woocommerce cart icon from wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, header

check my website if needed -> backlifeup.com

I've tried all of the following options but nothing seems to work:

In customization I don't have the general
https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/190-remove-or-edit-the-woocommerce-menu-icon

Does't work either...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhUZ1XfUb4g
https://secondlinethemes.com/disable-the-woocommerce-cart-icon/
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-woocommerce-cart-icon-from-nav-bar/
https://divibooster.com/hide-woocommerce-icon-from-divi-header/
https://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/remove-edit-woocommerce-menu-icon/

Comment: I don't think this question belongs on stackoverflow. I suggest asking your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ since it is not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was racking my brain trying to get that to work. Everything I saw pointed to:

```
.site-header-cart {
    display:none;
 }
```

***But that never worked for me!***

So I figured out something that does. Try this:

```
.cart-contents { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

simple you can customize your woocommerce website and add CSS code in adddition CSS  field

```
.site-header-cart {
    display:none;
 }
```

here is screenshot for more understand: https://ibb.co/bQW6CfD

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jangxx, but, here you go:

https://secondlinethemes.com/disable-the-woocommerce-cart-icon/